# Get last item from input iterator

Tags: c++

Is this correct behaviour for an input iterator, with regard to accessing the last item:

```
for(i=being();i!=end();i++){}
std::string s = i->toString();
return s;
```

Or should it throw an exception if I try to do this?

My iterator makes use of two c function calls: getFirst(...) and getNext(...)

Comment: That should work, except you spelled `begin` wrong.

Comment: @RedX, Daniel: That's wrong, `i == end()` after the end of the loop.

Comment: @Blood I'm moving to the end and then accessing the last item. Since the iterator has only the functions first and next I cant hop to the end in one step

Comment: Yes, yes. I wrote and then thought that's why i deleted my comment :P

Comment: @KennyTM You are right. I oversaw the {} at the end of the line.

Comment: @KennyTM: ah you're right. Good catch. It's been a while since I've dealt with iterators in c++.

Comment: @KennyTM Internally in the iterator, I have _isLast = True, but I'm still pointing to the last valid item I iterated over. So, it will work but should I instead cast an exception when dereferening an iterator when _isLast has become True. end() creates an iterator where isLast = True

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct behavior. The standard convention in C++ is that, `end()` should point to the place beyond the last item. Dereferencing it will cause undefined behavior (C++11 §24.2.2/5) in general.

You may make your own iterator to forgive dereferencing `end()` and exploit this, but it deviates from the standard practice, and make it hard for people to understand your code. I suggest you to throw an exception instead of returning the last item.

---

In standard C++, if all you have is a non-reproducible input iterator, it's not possible to "get the last item" unless you extract it every time:

```
auto it = begin();
auto val;
while (it != end()) {
    val = *it;
    ++ it;
}
return val;
```

But if you can create a *forward* iterator, then you could use

```
auto iter = begin();
decltype(iter) last_iter;
while (true) {
    last_iter = iter++;
    if (iter == end())
        break;
}
return last_iter;
```

Or if you creating the input iterator twice is cheap, you could do the iteration twice:

```
auto dist = std::distance(begin(), end());
auto last_iter = begin();
std::advance(last_iter, dist - 1);
return last_iter;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not OK, you'll be dereferencing `end()` and invoking undefined behaviour. Consider:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 42; ++i) ;
    std::cout << i;    // prints 42, did you expect 41?
}
```

Unless of course, you implemented your iterator class to do something sensible in this case. This not ok for standard library iterators, however.

Answer (score 0):

as far as stl containers are concerned, it is not correct behavior.

end()

> Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the list
>   container.

which would mean that after your loop, i does not point to a correct object (NOT the last element), but rather to a special defined end value, which would result in a access violation on calling i->toString().

Comment: I don't understand. Is i = end() being executed in my code? Just because i == end() is true does not mean that end()->toString() and i->toString() are the samething, or?

Comment: @Baz Yes, it's the same thing, actually. How else you think the condition would be true?

Comment: @Baz, if you write `int j = 3; j++;`, then you haven't actually *written* `j = 4`, and yet `j` has acquired the value of 4. Likewise, assigning an iterator and the incrementing it will eventually cause it to acquire the value of the last iterator in the sequence, also known as `end`.

Comment: @jrok Because internally in my iterator I have two things. A pointer to an object and a _isLast bool. So, just because _isLast is the same for end() and i, doesn't mean that i is not pointing to valid data. end() will never point to valid data. In operator++(), I call getNext() to see if more data is available, if not _isLast gets set to true but the pointer is lest alone (I'm using boost::shared_ptr).

Comment: @Baz When writing iterators, people usually want to mimic the behaviour of pointers (to some degree), so if `i == end()` is true, then it is sensible to expect that also `end() == i` is true and `i->someMethod()` is the same as `end()->someMethod()` which is expected to be undefined behaviour. Even though nothing really prevents you to write your own iterator in a completely different way, you should NOT do it, because everybody else will just end up being confused by the code..

Comment: Cool, I'm just interested in what is the standard way. Thanks.

Comment: What Fiktik said. When your loop ends, `i` *will be* an end iterator, even if you chose to implement it to point to a valid object.

Comment: @Baz as i said in my answer, i refer to the standard for c++ STL containers, which will behave like Rob Kennedy has stated in the comments. If you are asking about a c or c++ standard i can't tell. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ doesn't seem to have end() function defined, so it is up to you how you like it, but if your code will be used by others, i think it is a better way to stick to STL Standards

Comment: Should I change my operator++ function to return an iterator constructed with the default constructor if I have reached the end? The default constructor is used by end()

Comment: this depends on what kind of collection you are programming. if it is vector like, you could have end() point to the position where the next element would be added via push_back(). if you don't there are plenty of options with pros and cons. without discussing pros or cons to provide a solution:  you could create an empty Instance of the stored object in the Collections' constructor, which is assigned to begin and end.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is undefined, and you needn't do anything about it while implementing your iterator (no need to even throwing an exception). When implementing InputIterators, you only have to implement the operations

- `iter == iter2`, `iter != iter2`
- `*iter`, `iter->...`
- `++iter`, `(void)iter++`
- `*r++`

Of those, only the last one is hard (you have to return data from the previous position, while the iterator is moved to the next). It is typically implemented by a proxy, that remembers the old data.